# PAM authentication - automatically create user?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, pam, ubuntu-18.04, pam-ldap

I've finally got LDAP auth working on Ubuntu 18.04, however it only works if I first create the local user account (eg john.smith).

If I don't create the account first, it fails to bind to the LDAP server (AD).

Interestingly, it finds the user (auth.log shows the OU) however it then tries to bind with cn=john smith (missing the period in the middle).

Can I have PAM automatically create the local account and assign to a local Unix group?

Any help or pointers appreciated. Tim

Answer (score 0):

Usually implementing a central user management for Linux/Unix consists of two parts:

- PAM (what you already did) for user password authentication
- NSS (name service switch) config for integrating the remote user management (e.g. LDAP) to provide *passwd* and *group* maps

Normally you would use a local NSS/PAM service like sssd or nss-pam-ldapd (aka nslcd) but not add any local users.

PAM is configured in /etc/pam.d and NSS is configured in /etc/nsswitch.conf.